# Is this BNF grammar LL(1)?

Tags: parsing, grammar, bnf, ebnf, ll-grammar

Can someone please confirm for me if the following BNF grammar is LL(1):

```
S ::= A B B A
A ::= a
A ::=
B ::= b
B ::=
```

where S is the start symbol and non terminals A and B can derive to epsilon. I know if there are 2 or more productions in a single cell in the parse table, then the grammar isn't LL(1). But if a cell already contains epsilon, can we safely replace it with the new production when constructing the parse table?

Comment: Hmm maybe this isn't LL(1). If I am allowed to replace a cell in the parse table containing epsilon, like I mentioned in the question, then it won't detect FIRST/FOLLOW conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This grammar is ambiguous, and thus not LL(1), nor LL(k) for any k.

Take a single `a` or `b` as input, and see that it can be matched by either of the `A` or `B` references from `S`. Thus there are two different parse trees, proving that the grammar is ambiguous.